# Replicating "openssl sha1" in Node

Tags: node.js, openssl

How do I replicate the functionality of `openssl sha1` in pure Node? I've tried the code below, but I get different results when I run it versus when I do `openssl sha1`

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const key = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA50usDP38lUfcpTKmiGEt
oIeUQlJbSZi8/FNshil+Wf4/oyWPtzQeZL9NoWvtDoQit5dRpRU+5c2e5j3iYlOl
JcfBX6S/HRdrJHD8xirsNRVSMq4woQbd2QcniX1fwWLhJDU8XNaTYwEGQSTnkzxA
NpvwXMixAip+Nr0YMnZOToR6gu0t0euCUWpiypr/Zm40ppeAYxZzghHcVB4zbkOB
zN0h1rIRQ6It7fv12Kd3u6semGCEtJcYBo0ZJsucRQDUpTTGzuEChI35/Q94W4QH
evQ+JD68G2jQ/eOknYHoVUdjTYh3GJaiOpu+GDJXu3GHK18JjZmM0Lsmw/Jbypfj
wwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;


const sha1 = (str) => crypto.createHash('sha1').update(str).digest('hex');

pem.promisified.getPublicKey(key).then(({publicKey}) => {
  // Remove BEGIN and END blocks, newlines
  const stripped = publicKey.replace(/-----BEGIN.+KEY-----/, '').replace(/-----END.+KEY-----/,'').replaceAll('\n','');
  // Remove BEGIN and END blocks only
  const stripped2 = publicKey.replace(/-----BEGIN.+KEY-----/, '').replace(/-----END.+KEY-----/,'');
  // Remove newlines only
  const stripped3 = publicKey.replaceAll('\n','');

  console.debug("SHA1: ", sha1(publicKey));
  console.debug("SHA1 (stripped): ", sha1(stripped));
  console.debug("SHA1 (stripped2): ", sha1(stripped2));
  console.debug("SHA1 (stripped3): ", sha1(stripped3));
});
```

This outputs:

```
SHA1:  2f9ab4bb70dafe6e41e401977fabea42da4c0161
SHA1 (stripped):  7cf7d0322f96221d2075123b86c5095885d5025a
SHA1 (stripped2):  58a3c4ca8e5bd33b2d2b72ea6c5bff477b743c45
SHA1 (stripped3):  f80da8adcb7362fd7bd290fa6023f4b7d35a8757
```

By comparison, `openssl sha1` cacluates a digest of `64166b841bbb61c3f0dd7cefebb62bd79debce66`. How do I get this SHA1 without invoking the `openssl` binary?

Comment: How is `stripped` set/computed in the nodejs and what _exactly_ is the input to commandline? Check them and you'll find they are different somehow, perhaps in invisible characters like space, CR and/or LF, BOM, BIDI, etc.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 As you can see from the edit, while removing various non-payload characters does produce different SHA1 digests, none of the various stripping methods produce the same value that `openssl sha1` does. Furthermore, when I take (e.g.) the first "stripped" value and pass it through `openssl sha1`, I get a *different* SHA1 than the value that Node produces.

Comment: Keep the dash-BEGIN/END lines and the newlines AND add a newline/LF after the dash-END line (e.g. move the closing backtick to the next line) and you get 64166b841bbb61c3f0dd7cefebb62bd79debce66 . That is probably what you have in your commandline file, and it has long been the de facto standard that programs write, although RFC7468 belatedly made the final newline optional. For your `stripped` value I _do_ get the same result from commandline; check your file with `od -c` or `cat -A` to make sure it contains _exactly_ the base64 characters and not _any_ others.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H/T: [dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085) for figuring out it was the newline all along.

The problem was that my public key didn't have a trailing newline. Updated sketch (minus all the stripping):

```
const pem = require('pem');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const key = `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`

const sha1 = (str) => crypto.createHash('sha1').update(str).digest('hex');

pem.promisified.getPublicKey(key).then(({publicKey}) => {
  // getPublicKey doesn't append a newline
  publicKey = publicKey + '\n';
  console.debug({publicKey});
  console.debug("SHA1: ", sha1(publicKey));
});
```